# Sent value is seen as reference instead of value javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a page where I through ajax send links with onclicks function. The onclick function has some parameters, ( username, id, anotherid ).

```
echo '    <a href="#" onclick="openChat('.$rowUser['username'].','.$rowUser['id'].', '.$id.')"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></a>';
```

javascript code:

```
let openChat = function(username, id, anotherid){}
```

so the issue is here. The id and anotherid is seen as a value, while the username is seen as a reference, and not a string. Therefore it comes out as undefined. Cannot find the problem, help? 
Thanks! :)

Comment: Put (escaped) quotes around the username. Javascript now think it's a variable instead of a string. The reason it works for id is because that's a number (i assume)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap quotes around a string in js, but in your case you will have to add escape sequences because you are already using both single and double quotes already in this statement

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="openChat(\''.$rowUser['username'].'\','.$rowUser['id'].', '.$id.')"><i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i></a>';
```